# Can you identify this Marin bike?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

My black Marin bike was stolen this weekend and I need to identify the **year, model, and estimated price** for my insurance claim.

I have a picture of it below. I bought it around the year 1999 but don't have any receipts from then.

I'd welcome any suggestions. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Bikes can be hard to nail down, and the photo obscures many details.  Late 90s would be my guess at the date, but it's going to be hard to nail down a year.  And we don't do valuations here.

Comment: Simply find a similar spec model available retail now, ideally in the Marin brand, and submit that quote to your insurer as the "current model"  They'll probably deprecate the price and off you pennies for your bike at best.

Comment: Remember to include the extras - fenders/mudguards, helmet, lights, lock.  Whatever was on the bars not visible in photo, more lights.

Comment: Looking through the Marin archive the closest I can see is the Larkspur CS2 or Larkspur CS1, not much has changed since 2015 which is how far back the archive goes. If OP wants to upload more pics it would easier to narrow down. From what I can see only really the drivetrain changed on the Larkspur for each year.